# Disable the totaling of numeric properties when using linqpad Dump

Tags: linqpad

(I'm new to linqpad). When using the 'Dump' extension simply to display an object graph, if my object has a collection with numeric properties, say a collection of Books with a numeric Id, the Book.Id gets totaled for all books in that collection. Is there a way to disable this default behavior?

Comment: Heads up for new viewers: In LINQPad 6, Dump now takes an optional parameter called noTotals, you can use that to disable the feature. Ex.: `foo.Dump(noTotals: true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad doesn't show totals on columns it knows to be a primary key, but otherwise it has no way of knowing that that information isn't potentially useful.

If your books table doesn't have a primary key on ID, another issue is that you won't be able to update it via LINQ.

Comment: Thanks Joe. "Id" was a misnomer. Any non-primary-key numeric field. I had a sample table using int for ISBN and thought it odd the ISBN's would be totaled.

Comment: again: Nonetheless, LinqPad is just phenomenal. Having cached many of your posts to PDF, I hadn't visited your site for a long while. It is not only extremely practical, but solid quality. Huge thanks.